# python script for automatically start docker conainers

Tags: python, docker, automation, dockerfile

I want to start my docker container by using python script, but I am using windows while I accessing docker containers in my windows by 'XSHELL' terminal using of domain id is (dummy_name.com) and also have a password.

In my script I need while on the lap\pc automatically the all containers to start and run, by the python script

[here my xshell image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qemya.png)
[here the next password image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmolI.png)

after this two process i given to "vim.start.sh" this command then the containers are show the list.

Answer (score 0):

First. You can try using python's SSH module to go ahead and utilize the code to connect to the host. Here is an example

```
pip install paramiko
```

You can then use the following Python code to connect to the remote host and execute commands:

```
import paramiko

# Set the connection information for the remote host
host = "your_host"
port = 22
username = "your_username"
password = "your_password"

# Establish an SSH connection
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=host, port=port, username=username, password=password)

# Command to be executed
command = "ls -l" # You can replace the command with any command you want to execute

# Execute the command and get the output
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)

# Print the output
print(stdout.read().decode())

# Close the SSH connection
client.close()
```

The above is an example of connecting to a host using paramiko. You can make changes to the execution command line.
Please note that this is just a simple example and real applications may require more error handling and security measures. Also, using passwords for SSH connections may not be the most secure practice, **and you should consider using SSH keys for authentication.**

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
import os

os.system('docker start [container_id]')
```